# Set real IP in nginx reverse proxy tcp stream

Tags: nginx, tcp, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm running nginx as a reverse proxy and I want to pass real client IP to the backend service. Currently the traffic for the backend service originates at `127.0.0.1`. I'm using `stream` stanza to proxy all TCP traffic.

This is the nginx configuration

```
stream {

    server {

        listen <IP>:3333;
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:4444;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }
    
    server {
        listen            127.0.0.1:4444 proxy_protocol;
        proxy_pass        127.0.0.1:5555;
        #set_real_ip_from  $realip_remote_addr;
        set_real_ip_from  $proxy_protocol_addr;
    }
}
```

where `127.0.0.1:5555` is the backend service.

Nginx gives me the error

```
2023-12-28T12:18:58.656829521Z nginx: [emerg] host not found in set_real_ip_from "$proxy_protocol_addr" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:157
2023-12-28T12:19:58.902122518Z 2023/12/28 12:19:58 [emerg] 9#9: host not found in set_real_ip_from "$proxy_protocol_addr" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:157
```

What is the correct configuration or correct way to achieve this?